# Is there a template for an infinite sequence of parameters?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, parameters

There is a sequence of three types, say `std::string`, `int`, `int`. Is there a template in C++ to allow a function to take an infinite number of that sequence as parameters?

```
Function("Peter", 27, 89,
         "Max",   25, 72,
         "Frank", 32, 94,
         "David", 31, 98);
```

Comment: Do you mean function overloading?

Comment: C++11 variadic templates, anyone?

Comment: Yes, C++11 is allowed. I don't mean function overloading since I don't want to write a different function for every number of sequences. I am not familiar with variadic templates but this may be the technique I am looking for.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you intend to test whether a solution does indeed take an infinite number of parameters?

Comment: @juanchopanza It won't be mathematically infinite but I don't need that though. The template is resolved at compile time and different functions are generated. The point is just syntactic sugar and saving work.

Comment: I think you should say "arbitrary number of parameters"

Comment: @oseiskar Feel free to edit my question. I am not a native English speaker therefore my wording might be unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are several ways that came to my mind:

**variadic templates:** C++11

(covered by Emilio Garavaglia's answer, so I won't repeat)

**`initializer_list`s:** C++11

(similar to ChriZzZ's answer, but instead using `std::initializer_list` directly)

```
struct Sequence {
    std::string name;
    int numberA;
    int numberB;
};

#include <initializer_list>
void Function(std::initializer_list<Sequence> aLotOfData)
{
    for(const Sequence& s : aLotOfData)
    {
        // do operations on s.name, s.numberA, s.numberB
    }
}
//usage example
Function({ {"Peter", 27, 89}, {"Max", 25, 72} });
```

(here ends the list of straightforward solutions)

**overloading functions for arguments up to N:**

```
void Function(string n1, int a1, int b1) { /* ??? */ }
void Function(string n1, int a1, int b1, string n2, int a2, int b2) { /* ??? */ }
void Function(string n1, int a1, int b1, string n2, int a2, int b2, string n3, int a3, int b3) { /* ??? */ }
//usage example
Function("Peter", 27, 89, "Max", 25, 72);
```

Actually it's not that bad - if you can assume no one will call it with more than N args (bit of trivia: C standard recommends for C compilers to support minimum limit of 128 arguments) and that you won't code it manually (use preprocessor, but not necessarily the C preprocessor - because it's lowest common denominator for preprocessing. Boost uses its own preprocessor for variable arguments in non-C++11 code. Or you can generate C++ code with C++ program and include the output file in source code - now that's C++ metaprogramming ;-) ).

**array initialization and passing to function (or alternatively, with pointers and `sizeof`):**

```
struct Sequence
{
    std::string name;
    int numberA;
    int numberB;
};

#include <cstddef>
template<std::size_t N>
void Function(Sequence (&data)[N])
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        // do operations on data[i].name, data[i].numberA, data[i].numberB
    }
}
//usage example
Sequence args[] = { {"Peter", 27, 89}, {"Max", 25, 72} };
Function(args);
```

Similar solution can be used in C. (in C99 you can even use compound literals to supply arguments inline)

**method/function/operator chaining**:

```
struct Function
{
    const Function& operator()(string name, int na, int nb) const
    {
        // do operations to name, na, nb
        return *this;
    }

    void operator() const
    {
        //base case
        //optional here - return values
    }
};
//usage example
Function()("Peter", 27, 89)("Max", 25, 72)();
```

Chaining is used in C++ iostreams and in Boost.Assign. In this implementation, caller can forget to include the last parens, and function won't do the final things - there is sure to be better implementation.

**C varargs**:

```
#include <cstdarg>
void Function(std::size_t count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, count);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        string name = va_arg(ap, const char*);
        int na = va_arg(ap, int);
        int nb = va_arg(ap, int);
        // do operations on name, na, nb
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
//usage example (the first argument refers to count of arguments - it has to match)
Function(2, "Peter", 27, 89, "Max", 25, 72);
```

Very, very bad solution. We had to discard `std::string` as argument and replace it with `const char*` as non-PODs can't be passed to varargs function (or we could pass pointers to `std::string`). Note that *any* mistake here will cause undefined behaviour. The compiler won't check type of args and will blindly trust us that we passed arguments of the right type.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is "*what do you have to do with that sequence*".

It is possible to take an arbitrary sequence of parameters and giving them 3 by 3 to a function taking just 3:

```
void Function(string n, int a, int b) 
{ /* base action here */ }

template<class... Others>
void Function(string n1, int a1, int b1, const Others&... t)
{
    Function(n1, a1, b1);
    Function(t...);
}
```

It compiles only if the parameter types matches repeatedly the base function ones.

Comment: Is there a way to match the sequence `A, B, C` into `vector.push_back(make_pair(A, make_pair(B, C)))` without using an external helper function or lambda?

Comment: @danijar Insert it in base function, unless you want to return the vector, then helper functions may be the easiest way.

Comment: I tried that but Visual Studio 11 gives me some compiler errors. The first one reads `error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name`.

Comment: @danijar: Looks like it misinterpreted the `...` after the `class` keyword. Check if the compiler properly supports varadic templates (may be you have to specify a switch to enable c++11 features)

Comment: I found on [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) that variadic templates aren't supported by VS11 sadly. Can you think of a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

just use a struct and some kind of container.

```
void Function(std::vector<Sequence> aLotOfData);


struct Sequence {
    std::string name;
    int numberA;
    int numberB;
};
```

Comment: Usage example: `Function({ {"Peter", 27, 89}, {"Max", 25, 72} });`

Comment: I'll do when Visual Studio supports initializer lists with stl containers.

Comment: or use `std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, int>>`